# Assign another function "this" from the button inside ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I have `li` tag with `*ngFor`

```
<li *ngFor="let items of buttons">
  <button (click)="newMap(items.id, $event)">
    {{ items.name }}
  </button>
</li>
```

So, buttons array it looks like this:

```
buttons = [
  {name: 'Berlin', id: 'mapBerlin'},
  {name: 'New York', id: 'mapNewYork'},
  {name: 'Tokyo', id: 'mapTokyo'}
]
```

and I assign `(click)` method on tag `button`:

```
(click)="newMap(items.id, $event)"
```

TypeScript:

```
newMap($event) {
  console.log($event)
}
```

When I click on the button number 1, I've got this message in console:

- mapBerlin

Button number 2:

- mapNewYork

etc.

How to make a function like this ?:

```
newMap(this.id) {
  this.markers = this.id
}
```

I would like change `this.markers` to `this.id` `(this.mapBerlin)` `(this.mapNewYork)` etc.

Comment: can u show the declaration of `markers` in your code ?
and can u explain what u mean by this : "`(this.mapBerlin) ` 
  `(this.mapNewYork)` etc." ?

Comment: How have you declared (this.mapBerlin) (this.mapNewYork) variables in your code?

Answer (score 1):

This is fine

```
<li *ngFor="let items of buttons">
  <button (click)="newMap(items.id, $event)">
    {{ items.name }}
  </button>
</li>
```

Your function

```
newMap(id, event){
this.markers = id}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your code should work like that:

```js
newMap(newId) {
  this.markers = newId;
}
```

Just assign the passed id.

Comment: Yeah, I have too:
'mapTokyo'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li *ngFor="let items of buttons">
    <button (click)="newMap(items)">
    {{ items.name }}
    </button>
</li>

newMap = (item) => {
    this.markers = item.id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change context of the function:

You can just do this:

```
newMap(id, event){
    this.markers = id;
}
```

If you are still looking to modify context `this` do it like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let items of buttons">
  <button (click)="newMap.call(items, $event)">
    {{ items.name }}
  </button>
</li>
```

And in TS

```
const componenContext = this;
.
.
.
newMap(event){
    componenContext.markers = this.id;
}
```

But i wouldn't recommend this approach. It is really hacky one.

Answer (score 0):

This code is OK:

```
newMap = (item) => {
    this.markers = item.id;
}
```

But I have this message in console:

```
'mapTokyo'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
buttons = [
  {name: 'Berlin', id: this.mapBerlin},
  {name: 'New York', id: this.mapNewYork},
  {name: 'Tokyo', id: this.mapTokyo}
]
```

then you received in id the whole object